# Change background when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can somebody help or assist me ?I have been searching and reading but I am  nowhere to find answers. I am kinda not into jquery so I need help. 
I  have a drop down menu. What I would like to achieve from that is , when I click the sub menu with sub sub drop down menu it changes background. Now it worked, the background changes, but it applies to its sibling elements which has also a drop down. I would like to change the background of the element which is clicked.

The jquery:

```
    $('.withsub a').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).siblings('.tmenu-subs02').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).siblings('.tmenu-subs02').hide();
        $('.withsub').removeClass('clicked');
    } else {
        $(this).siblings('.tmenu-subs02').show();
        $('.withsub').addClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

please see [actual demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jsnoob/j2Lxrxf1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2Lxrxf1/2/):

```
$('.withsub a').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).siblings('.tmenu-subs02').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).siblings('.tmenu-subs02').hide();
        $(this).parent().removeClass('clicked');
    } else {
        $(this).siblings('.tmenu-subs02').show();
        $(this).parent().addClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are targetting all `.withsub` elements whereas you need to only target closest `.withsub` parent element.

You need to use:

```
$('.withsub a').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).siblings('.tmenu-subs02').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).siblings('.tmenu-subs02').hide();
        $(this).closest('.withsub').removeClass('clicked');
    } else {
        $(this).siblings('.tmenu-subs02').show();
        $(this).closest('.withsub').addClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ny5eLc6/)**

You can also narrow down your code by using `.toggle()` and `.toggleClass()`

```
$('.withsub a').on('click', function () {
        $(this).siblings().toggle();
        $(this).closest('.withsub').toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

**[Demo using toggle and toggleclass](http://jsfiddle.net/te3L988L/)**

Comment: @Sharon: glad it helps. go for second solution with toggle and toggleclass.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like following. Use **[.children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)**

```
$('.withsub').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).children('.tmenu-subs02').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).children('.tmenu-subs02').hide();
            $(this).removeClass('clicked');
        } else {
            $(this).children('.tmenu-subs02').show();
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
        }
    });
```

Check [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2Lxrxf1/4/)